# footer which fill the whole bottom

Tags: css

I would like to fill the whole free bottom space (white color) in case of display with a big width (bigger than content) so how to set css3 style to do this?

[image]

CSS:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footer .copyright {
    font-family:Lato;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:0.9em;
  font-weight:400;
}
.footer-color-black,
.footer-transparent {
  background-color: #595324;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3re9wbr2/1/

Comment: where your code ? put in jsfiddle or here

Comment: @Sumitpatel https://jsfiddle.net/3re9wbr2/1/

Comment: @Utkanos set min-height and height:100% in separate divs?

Comment: Please include the code in the question, as per the SO guidelines. People shouldn't have to go outside to find out what the issue is.

Comment: You want the footer to stick to the bottom?

Comment: @LGSon hm stick it to the bottom with not dropping padding between content and footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, adding `margin: 0` to the html/body tag will give you this

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer .copyright {
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.footer-color-black,
.footer-transparent {
  background-color: #595324;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-area">
      <div class="gallerygrid">
        <h5>content ldosalodaslodlsoalodslaodasol</h5>
        <h5>content ldosalodaslodlsoalodslaodasol</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer footer-big footer-color-black" data-color="black">
  <div class="copyright">
    ©
    <script>
      document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
    </script> · Lorem Ipsum · All Copyright reserved
  </div>
</footer>
```

Second, adding a `wrapper` using `display: flex` with a `min-width: 100vh` and give the `.footer` `flex: 1` will give you this

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section {
}

.footer {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.footer .copyright {
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.footer-color-black,
.footer-transparent {
  background-color: #595324;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title-area">
        <div class="gallerygrid">
          <h5>content ldosalodaslodlsoalodslaodasol</h5>
          <h5>content ldosalodaslodlsoalodslaodasol</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer footer-big footer-color-black" data-color="black">
    <div class="copyright">
      ©
      <script>
        document.write(new Date().getFullYear())

      </script> · Lorem Ipsum · All Copyright reserved
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: It's sticky footer. I'm not sure how I can describe my problem. For example: footer on the middle screen and to the bottom should be filled by color of footer.

Comment: @test Updated my 2:nd sample, better ?

Comment: much better! That's what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a sticky footer.

[Ryan Fait's method](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/) works well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not what I want. Maybe the easiest method will be adding the div ( second background of body )